# AdminLTE info-box with right div

Tags: css

Hello I use [AdminLTE](https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html) template and I would like to add dropdown menu to info-box. My idea is dropdown button in right side of info-box. Here is my code:

```
<div class="info-box info-box-sm dropdown">
  <div class="info-box-icon bg-aqua">
    <i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="info-box-content">
    <span class="info-box-text">Title</span>
    <span class="info-box-number">369 records</span>
  </div>

  <div class="info-box-dropdown">
      <!-- Right side button for dropdown -->
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 .info-box.info-box-sm { min-height: 45px; margin-bottom: 15px; font-size: 15px; }
.info-box.info-box-sm small { font-size: 12px; }
.info-box.info-box-sm .info-box-icon { height: 52px; width: 52px; font-size: 27px; line-height: 52px; }
.info-box.info-box-sm .info-box-content {
  margin-left: 52px;
}
.info-box .info-box-content .info-box-text{
    font-size: 15px!important;
}
.info-box .info-box-content .info-box-number{
    font-size: 15px!important;
}
.info-box.info-box-sm.dropdown{
    float: left;
}
.info-box.info-box-sm.dropdown .info-box-icon{
    background: blue;
}
.info-box.info-box-sm.dropdown .info-box-content{
    width: 70%;
    background: red;
    float: left;
}
.info-box.info-box-sm.dropdown .info-box-dropdown{
    float: right;
    background: blue;
}
```

And this is result:

[image]

I need this:

[image]

Thank you for help

Comment: Why I got unvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.info-box.info-box-sm {
  min-height: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.info-box.info-box-sm small {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.info-box.info-box-sm .info-box-icon {
  height: 52px;
  width: 52px;
  font-size: 27px;
  line-height: 52px;
}

.info-box.info-box-sm .info-box-content {
  //margin-left: 52px;
  height: 52px;
}

.info-box .info-box-content .info-box-text {
  font-size: 15px!important;
}

.info-box .info-box-content .info-box-number {
  font-size: 15px!important;
}

.info-box.info-box-sm.dropdown {
  float: left;
}

.info-box.info-box-sm.dropdown .info-box-icon {
  background: blue;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.info-box.info-box-sm.dropdown .info-box-content {
  width: 70%;
  background: red;
  float: left;
}

.info-box.info-box-sm.dropdown .info-box-dropdown {
  float: right;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="info-box info-box-sm dropdown">
  <div class="info-box-icon bg-aqua">
    <i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="info-box-content">
    <span class="info-box-text">Title</span>
    <span class="info-box-number">369 records</span>
  </div>

  <div class="info-box-dropdown">
    <!-- Right side button for dropdown -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, `display: inline-flex;` is good solution, but I must add `display` to `.info-box.info-box-sm.dropdown`.